# How to deal with different vector-dimensions for embeddings and search with pgvector?

Tags: postgresql, vector, pgvector, retrieval-augmented-generation

I use Postgres with the **pgvector**-extension for storing embeddings from OpenAI as the data source for my RAG pipeline.

Until now, the best practice was to use the embedding model `text-embedding-ada-002` providing vectors with a dimension of 1536.

Today, OpenAI has announced 2 new models, `text-embedding-3-small` and `text-embedding-3-large`, providing various dimensions 512 and 1536 and respectively 256, 1024 and 3072.

My question is, how can I deal with multiple vector dimensions on the same table offering the same query.

Currently, my table looks like this:

```
create table if not exists public.embeddings
 (
    id         serial primary key,
    embedding  vector(1536) not null

    // ... some more columns, but irrelevant for the given context
)

create index if not exists embeddings_embedding_idx
    on public.embeddings using ivfflat (embedding public.vector_cosine_ops);
```

For querying, I use a stored function:

```
create or replace function match_embeddings(
    query_embedding vector(1536),
    match_threshold float,
    match_count int
)
    RETURNS table(j json)
AS
$$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
        select row_to_json(r)
        from (select e.id,
                     1 - (e.embedding <=> query_embedding) as similarity
              from embeddings e
              where
                1 - (e.embedding <=> query_embedding) > match_threshold
              order by similarity desc
              limit match_count) r;
END
$$ language plpgsql;
```

At the moment, the full setup is based on a fixed dimension size for the vector: 1536.
Unfortunately, `pgvector` does not provide a variable dimension size. If I have a column `vector(1536)`, it must be filled with an array consisting of exactly 1536 values. Providing fewer values will result in an error.

I wonder, if I can easily increase the vector storage until the current required maximum (3072) and, for instance, store the applied vector size inside the table to identify at any time, which kind of dimension has been stored.

The main questions are:

1. should I *right-pad* existing vectors, which have a dimension of 1536, with zeros to fit into 3072 dimensions? Will this destroy any query mechanism?
2. Or should I rather add multiple columns for each required dimension, like `embedding_1536 vector(1536)`, `embedding_3072 vector(3072)`?
3. or should I rather have multiple embedding-tables providing each a vector-column providing the corresponding dimension?
4. or something else, which is not in my head as of now

Any useful ideas, hints, remarks, or solutions are very much welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [variable](https://github.com/pgvector/pgvector/issues/426) embedding column?

```
CREATE TABLE items (id bigserial PRIMARY KEY, embedding vector);
INSERT INTO items (embedding) VALUES ('[1,2,3]'), ('[4,5]');
SELECT * FROM items WHERE vector_dims(embedding) = 3 ORDER BY embedding <-> '[3,1,2]' LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: WOW! Thats wonderful, thank you! In order  to use indexes it would be useful to have another column indicating the "vector_dims" value as integer with an INDEX on that. Or can you recommend another approach for that?